# TypeError: user_followers() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python

I get this error:

```html
TypeError: user_followers() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

in my python script, running this lines of code:

```html
origin = api.username_info('edelfilm')
user_id = origin['user']['pk']
followers = []
results = api.user_followers(user_id)
```

The function is defined in another script like this:

```html
    def user_followers(self, user_id, rank_token, **kwargs):
        """
        Get user followers

        :param user_id:
        :param rank_token: Required for paging through a single feed and can be generated with
            :meth:`generate_uuid`. You should use the same rank_token for paging through a single user followers.
        :param kwargs:
            - **query**: Search within the user followers
            - **max_id**: For pagination
        :return:
        """
        raise_if_invalid_rank_token(rank_token)

        endpoint = 'friendships/{user_id!s}/followers/'.format(**{'user_id': user_id})
        query_params = {
            'rank_token': rank_token,
        }
        query_params.update(kwargs)
        res = self._call_api(endpoint, query=query_params)
        if self.auto_patch:
            [ClientCompatPatch.list_user(u, drop_incompat_keys=self.drop_incompat_keys)
             for u in res.get('users', [])]
        return res
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you dont pass `rank_token`.

Comment: What part of the error message is confusing to you?

Comment: And how do I pass rank_token? I do not get it…

Comment: @daniel_e You defined function to take 3 arguments: self, user_id, rank_token. However, `api.user_followers(user_id)` has only self and user_id. You should call it like `api.user_followers(user_id, rank_token)`.

Answer (score 2):

First Define the variable rank_token in your code

```
origin = api.username_info('edelfilm')
user_id = origin['user']['pk']
rank_token = 1 #Assuming it takes an integer value
followers = []
```

and then pass it as the third parameter to your method

```
results = api.user_followers(user_id, rank_token)
```